# iPhone Core Animation - Drawing a Circle

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I wish to create an animation. The best way I can explain this is if you can imagine drawing a circle. It starts at the top or 12 o clock and draws clockwise all the way around until it becomes a complete circle over the space of 10 or so seconds.

The closet I have come to this is to draw a point rotating around a center point using Core Animation (using the sample code [here](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-1)). But I am at a loss on how to draw the circle? Any suggestions are very welcome.

Many Thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to draw a circle sector where the angle increases until it becomes a complete circle (filled) or just drawing a curved line until it becomes a complete circle (just the outline, not filled)?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist im trying to draw a curved line until it becomes a complete circle, just the outline not filled :)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

What you really should do is to **animate the stroke of a CAShapeLayer** where the path is a circle. This will be accelerated using Core Animation and is less messy then to draw part of a circle in -drawRect:.

The code below will create a circle shape layer in the center of the screen and animate the stroke of it clockwise so that it looks as if it is being drawn. You can of course use any shape you'd like. (You can read [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/) on Ole Begemanns blog to learn more about how to animate the stroke of a shape layer.)

**Note:** that the stoke properties are not the same as the border properties on the layer. To change the width of the stroke you should use "lineWidth" instead of "borderWitdh" etc.

```
// Set up the shape of the circle
int radius = 100;
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
// Make a circular shape
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) 
                                         cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
// Center the shape in self.view
circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-radius, 
                              CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-radius);

// Configure the apperence of the circle
circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 5;

// Add to parent layer
[self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];

// Configure animation
CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.duration            = 10.0; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..

// Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

// Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

// Add the animation to the circle
[circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

Comment: Thanks David for this great peace of code! I have question: How do you animate filling of entire circle, and not just curved line? (the first thing you asked bennythemink in comment on his question)

Comment: David, thank you. I was thinking of the same thing, basically just to increase line width until full circle, just thought if there's some other way, since I was looking for some animations which animate directly circle fill, not stroke, but I wasn't able to find them.

Comment: There are other ways. You could create a custom layer and animate it. Have a look at [this great tutorial for animating pie slices with a custom CALayer](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/)

Comment: Thanks once more. I have one question more, it can be interesting to this theme, so I will ask it here: You showed how to fill curved line (or entire circle) with solid color. How can I achieve gradient fill of that surface I am drawing?

Comment: You would have to draw a full gradient in a separate layer and use the animated circle as a mask. When you animate the fill of the circle mask, the gradient will be become visible.

Comment: Epic. Thanks man, it's working. Many thanks for advices. To bad I can't give you gold medal myself.

Comment: Cool! Can I stop the animation half way without drawing the whole circle?

Comment: @CyrilMestrom You can animate to `0.5` instead of `1.0` to only fill half the circle. `drawAnimation.toValue = @0.5;`

Comment: Thanks, but tried that already and it animates halfway but then draws the whole thing at once..

Comment: @CyrilMestrom Yes, all animations behave that way. Once the animation completes they go back to the "real" value. You also have to set the `strokeEnd` property to `0.5` on the layer. It wasn't done in this example because 1.0 is the default.

Comment: I changed my code to use `bezierPathWithArcCenter` instead of `bezierPathWithRoundedRect`, because I prefer the coordinates system it gives me, plus the ability to animate the rotation in the opposite direction... But this saved me a lot of time so many thanks! :)

Comment: For those interested in @jowie's approach, I've added some code to do it this way as an answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another solution to the problem, based off @David's answer. This approach lets you set the direction of the circle's animation, and offers slightly more control. **Edit:** I've written a blog post on [how to draw a circle with Swift](http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/08/17/draw-circle-core-animation-swift-ios/), which I'll try to keep up to date with the betas. Check there if the code below doesn't work for you.

```
let radius = 100.0

// Create the circle layer
var circle = CAShapeLayer()

// Set the center of the circle to be the center of the view
let center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - radius, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - radius)

let fractionOfCircle = 3.0 / 4.0

let twoPi = 2.0 * Double(M_PI)
// The starting angle is given by the fraction of the circle that the point is at, divided by 2 * Pi and less
// We subtract M_PI_2 to rotate the circle 90 degrees to make it more intuitive (i.e. like a clock face with zero at the top, 1/4 at RHS, 1/2 at bottom, etc.)
let startAngle = Double(fractionOfCircle) / Double(twoPi) - Double(M_PI_2)
let endAngle = 0.0 - Double(M_PI_2)
let clockwise: Bool = true

// `clockwise` tells the circle whether to animate in a clockwise or anti clockwise direction
circle.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(startAngle), endAngle: CGFloat(endAngle), clockwise: clockwise).CGPath

// Configure the circle
circle.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
circle.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
circle.lineWidth = 5

// When it gets to the end of its animation, leave it at 0% stroke filled
circle.strokeEnd = 0.0

// Add the circle to the parent layer
self.layer.addSublayer(circle)

// Configure the animation
var drawAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
drawAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0

// Animate from the full stroke being drawn to none of the stroke being drawn
drawAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(double: fractionOfCircle)
drawAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)

drawAnimation.duration = 30.0

drawAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

// Add the animation to the circle
circle.addAnimation(drawAnimation, forKey: "drawCircleAnimation")
```

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution to this problem, code below. I seem to have messed up in my explanation of the problem at hand so rewrote it as another question that got answered with the correct solution, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004972/iphone-drawing-a-curved-line-until-it-becomes-a-circle-animation/8005558#8005558)

thanks everyone for their advice!

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code

    CGRect allRect = self.bounds;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw background
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, self.strokeValueRed, self.strokeValueGreen, self.strokeValueBlue, self.strokeValueAlpha); // white
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);

    // Draw progress
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(allRect.size.width / 2, allRect.size.height / 2);
    CGFloat radius = (allRect.size.width - 4) / 2;
    CGFloat startAngle = - ((float)M_PI / 2); // 90 degrees
    CGFloat endAngle = (self.progress * 2 * (float)M_PI) + startAngle;
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a partial fix. I found the following code that draws segments of a circle. Its basically a UIView subclass that gets its drawRect fired every time its progress should be updated. The only question I have now is how would I change it so that instead of drawing sections or slices it would just draw the circle stroke?

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    // Drawing code

    CGRect allRect = self.bounds;
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectInset(allRect, 2.0f, 2.0f);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw background
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, self.strokeValueRed, self.strokeValueGreen, self.strokeValueBlue, self.strokeValueAlpha); // white
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f); // translucent white
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);

    // Draw progress
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(allRect.size.width / 2, allRect.size.height / 2);
    CGFloat radius = (allRect.size.width - 4) / 2;
    CGFloat startAngle = - ((float)M_PI / 2); // 90 degrees
    CGFloat endAngle = (self.progress * 2 * (float)M_PI) + startAngle;
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // white
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```