# How to animate an arc implemented by using CGContext in iOS?

Tags: ios, animation, cgcontext

I use Quartz function CGContextAddArc to draw an arc.But I want to make an animation that show how the arc is drawn.but I have no idea about how to implement it .

Comment: Already answered here perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8021277/128317