# How to animate line from start point to end point

Tags: iphone

Here is the code which draws a vertical line in graph.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {    

           AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

     UIBezierPath  *breakFastValuePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [breakFastValuePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(89, 288)];
        [breakFastValuePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(89,288-delegate.breakFastTotalamt)];
        [breakFastValuePath closePath];
        [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
        breakFastValuePath.lineWidth = 10;
        [breakFastValuePath stroke];
    }
```

How to make the line animating from starting point to end point wen view is loaded?

Comment: why don't you animate the view on which line is drawn

Comment: what do u mean? i am putting a graph.. so when graph appears line should start moving from starting point till end point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the `strokeEnd` from 0.0 to 1.0 to give the effect that the line along its path from start to end. Look at [this question (about drawing a circle in Core Animation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle/8021051#8021051) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to take a different approach.
I will show you an example for a horizontal line, the vertical case will be very similar.
Use a normal UIView to represent your line with an initial frame like:

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:  
                   CGRectMake(startX,startY,1,lineThickness)];//Line starts as 1 pixel long.
//Then you need to animate this inside loadView:
[UIView animateWithDuration:1//Amount of time the animation takes.
                  delay:0//Amount of time after which animation starts.
                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut//How the animation will behave.
             animations:^{
                //here you can either set a CGAffineTransform, or change your view's frame.
                //Both will work just fine.
                lineView = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (
                scaleForX,//say 100, Now the line will be a 100 pixels long.
                scaleForY//say 1, Maintain line thickness.      
                //direction.
                //Note* you could also set the frame for a similar effect.
                //view's frame.
                //lineView.frame = CGRectMake(startX,startY,finalLength,lineThickness)
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){//This block is called when the animation completes.
                 NSLog(@"Done!");
             }];
```