# CALayer as SubLayer Not Visible

Tags: ios4, core-animation, invisible, quartz-core

I am trying to built an animated circle which would be drawn clockwise until it becomes complete circle as illustrated in [iPhone Core Animation - Drawing a Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle)

Problem is that `CALayer` object is not added or build. I tested and saw that it is not accessing my `drawInContext:CGContextRef` and `animatingArc` methods.

What so far I have done is:

**In AnimateArc.h**

```
@interface AnimateArc : CALayer {

CAShapeLayer *circle;
}

-(void) animatingArc;

@end
```

**In AnimateArc.m**

```
-(void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
CGFloat radius = 50.0;
circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

//make a circular shape
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)/2, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)/2);    

//center the shape in self.view
circle.position = centerPoint;

//configure appearence of circle
circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 5;                                           

/*CGPointMake((self.contentsCenter.size.width), (self.contentsCenter.size.height));*/

//path the circle
CGContextAddArc(ctx, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radius, 0.0, 2 * M_PI, 0);
CGContextClosePath(ctx);

//fill it
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(ctx); }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
-(void) animatingArc
{
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"arcEnd"];
anim.duration = 20.0; //animate over 20 seconds
anim.repeatCount = 1.0; //animate only once
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO; //Reamin there after completion

//animate from start to end
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0f];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:150.0f];

//experiment with timing to get appearence to look the way you want
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

//add animation to circle
[circle addAnimation:anim forKey:@"animatingArc"]; 
}
```

/////////////////////

```
//needed since key not part of animatable properties
+(BOOL) needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key
{
if([key isEqualToString:@"arcEnd"])
    return YES;
else
    return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];

}

//ensure custom properties copied to presentation layer
-(id) initWithLayer:(id)layer
{
if((self = [super initWithLayer:layer]))
{
    if ([layer isKindOfClass:[AnimateArc class]])
    {
        AnimateArc *other = (AnimateArc *) layer;
        [other setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
return self; }
```

And finally in my viewController,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:AnimateArcObject];
[AnimateArcObject animatingArc];
 }
```

Apology for bad formatting.... Please can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? I have also doubt that my code can crash at any place after accessing those two functions since I am novice about Core Animation and haven't got any idea that I am in right direction or not.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little searching, I thought that I am going in wrong direction. So I deleted this `AnimateArc` file and added new one which is **inheriting from `UIViewController`.**

Then in `viewDidLoad` Method, I wrote the code from  [this link](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-1) to create circle and animations using path.

In *parent view controller*, I added `AnimatedArc ViewController's subview`. Now its working perfectly :)

Answer (score 21):

From my painful experience with CoreAnimation, you must **always** set the `bounds` property of *any* `CALayer` you instantiate.

So, you're layer is not showing because you are missing something like:

`layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);`

you should place this as soon as you instantiate the layer, and make it a habit to do so, so you don't fall into it again.

As for your code crashing, sorry. It's too distributed and I am not sure how it's linked together, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But setting bounds still didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: It helped me, but didn't fully solve it. The layer is now drawing on screen, but slightly offset from the parent view/layer even when I set the layer's bounds to the parent views frame. I'm missing something fundamental it seems.

Comment: @tracicot you __must__ set the bounds of the layer to origin `(0, 0)`. Then, use the center property to change the position. You can also set the layer frame directly to control the position.

Comment: Thanks, @Mazyod. I've send the bounds as you said, and the frame to be the same frame as the parent view in order to control the layer's position, but still no luck.

Comment: Thanks for this. It was a lifesaver.