# Gradient Colors not changing based on Button isSelected State

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, gradient

I made a custom gradient Button, such that I can change the gradient color on different states:

```
class GradientButton: UIButton {

public var buttongradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            buttongradient.colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#ef473a")!, UIColor(hexString: "#cb2d3e")!].map { $0.cgColor }
        } else {
            buttongradient.colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#29a1e2")! , UIColor(hexString: "#485ac8")!].map { $0.cgColor }
        }
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addthegradientLayer()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.addthegradientLayer()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.addthegradientLayer()

}

func addthegradientLayer() {
    //the cells gradient colors
    buttongradient.frame = self.bounds
    buttongradient.cornerRadius = buttongradient.frame.height / 2
    buttongradient.colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#29a1e2")! , UIColor(hexString: "#485ac8")!].map { $0.cgColor }
    buttongradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    buttongradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(buttongradient, at: 0)
}
```

When I run this code, the button background is clear. No Gradient showing.

**EDIT**

As in the comments suggested:

```
buttongradient.frame = self.bounds
```

is the solution.

**Follow up Problem**

Now I realise, that the gradient does not change colors based on the isSelected state.

Comment: `buttongradient.frame = self.frame`=> `buttongradient.frame = self.bounds` seems better.

Comment: That's the solution!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955210/frame-and-bounds-of-cashapelayer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595555/calayer-as-sublayer-not-visible etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Frame and Bounds of CAShapeLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955210/frame-and-bounds-of-cashapelayer)

Comment: You should update the gradient only if the bounds really change otherwise you will have a huge performance problem. I know because I was fixing a similar one recently. You also probably want to use `isHighlighted` and not `isSelected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

1. As you already now, you have to use `self.bounds` to update the layer frame.
2. Changing the layer in initializers is not necessary. The `layoutSubviews` is always called before rendering.
3. If your aim is to change colors when the button is pressed, you want to use `isHighlighted`, not `isSelected`.
4. Every layout will rewrite your color values, remove `buttongradient.colors` from the layout method.
5. There is no need to use strings for hexadecimal color definition. I would recommend to use integers, e.g. `0x29a1e2` (see [How to use hex colour values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263007/how-to-use-hex-colour-values/24263296#24263296)).

```
class GradientButton: UIButton {

    public let buttongradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override var isSelected: Bool {  // or isHighlighted?
        didSet {
            updateGradientColors()
        }
    }

    func updateGradientColors() {
        let colors: [UIColor]

        if isSelected {
           colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#ef473a")!, UIColor(hexString: "#cb2d3e")!]
        } else {
           colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#29a1e2")!, UIColor(hexString: "#485ac8")!]
        }

        buttongradient.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupGradient()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupGradient()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.updateGradient()
    }

    func setupGradient() {
        buttongradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        buttongradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(buttongradient, at: 0)

        updateGradientColors()
    }

    func updateGradient() {
        buttongradient.frame = self.bounds
        buttongradient.cornerRadius = buttongradient.frame.height / 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Being new to Swift, what is the best way of calling this code from a UIButton?  Is it by calling the updateGradientColors()  function?  I want to be able to change the colour of the UIButton when pressing it, moving onto the next UIView and coming back to the original UIView and the colour of the button is in the New Colour.