# How can I program a rotating circular animation such as this one (picture attached)? Android

Tags: android, animation, graphics, android-animation

I am developing an app & just  built its logical part. Now I  want to design this app like in famous timer apps.for examples:

[image: http://goo.gl/N3qS1]
[image]

The thing I want is the outer Circle that fills with every trigger of some event or with increment of number. I actually don't know that is it animation part (like to be built in flash or what) or just possible by coding in android itself using its inbuilt properties and features.
So anybody if tell explain me what tools are used or any reference tutorial that can explain things from bottom. I really don't know any thing of designing . Any code for this??

Comment: You previously tagged this question Core Animation (iOS framework). I could tell you how it's done on iOS but I doubt that it will answer your question.

Comment: I didn't knew that its iOS framework. I thought it is just animation related to core or something like that. My fault

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist could you provide a link for the iOS implementation of this?

Comment: Actually, I seem to have found some guidance from one of your comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle/8021051#8021051)

Answer (score 6):

Will this do?

*Update:* Now also correctly handles real world time.

**Sample Screenshot:** [image: Sample screenshot]

**Code:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.view.View;

import android.graphics.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new CircularCountdown(this));
    }

    private static class CircularCountdown extends View {

        private final Paint backgroundPaint;
        private final Paint progressPaint;
        private final Paint textPaint;

        private long startTime;
        private long currentTime;
        private long maxTime;

        private long progressMillisecond;
        private double progress;

        private RectF circleBounds;
        private float radius;
        private float handleRadius;
        private float textHeight;
        private float textOffset;

        private final Handler viewHandler;
        private final Runnable updateView;

        public CircularCountdown(Context context) {
            super(context);

            // used to fit the circle into
            circleBounds = new RectF();

            // size of circle and handle
            radius = 200;
            handleRadius = 10;

            // limit the counter to go up to maxTime ms
            maxTime = 5000;

            // start and current time
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            currentTime = startTime;


            // the style of the background
            backgroundPaint = new Paint();
            backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            backgroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            backgroundPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
            backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#4D4D4D"));  // dark gray

            // the style of the 'progress'
            progressPaint = new Paint();
            progressPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            progressPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            progressPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            progressPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
            progressPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00A9FF"));    // light blue

            // the style for the text in the middle
            textPaint = new TextPaint();
            textPaint.setTextSize(radius / 2);
            textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

            // text attributes
            textHeight = textPaint.descent() - textPaint.ascent();
            textOffset = (textHeight / 2) - textPaint.descent();


            // This will ensure the animation will run periodically
            viewHandler = new Handler();
            updateView = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    // update current time
                    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    // get elapsed time in milliseconds and clamp between <0, maxTime>
                    progressMillisecond = (currentTime - startTime) % maxTime;

                    // get current progress on a range <0, 1>
                    progress = (double) progressMillisecond / maxTime;

                    CircularCountdown.this.invalidate();
                    viewHandler.postDelayed(updateView, 1000/60);
                }
            };
            viewHandler.post(updateView);
        }



        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // get the center of the view
            float centerWidth = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
            float centerHeight = canvas.getHeight() / 2;


            // set bound of our circle in the middle of the view
            circleBounds.set(centerWidth - radius,
                    centerHeight - radius,
                    centerWidth + radius,
                    centerHeight + radius);


            // draw background circle
            canvas.drawCircle(centerWidth, centerHeight, radius, backgroundPaint);

            // we want to start at -90°, 0° is pointing to the right
            canvas.drawArc(circleBounds, -90, (float)(progress*360), false, progressPaint);

            // display text inside the circle
            canvas.drawText((double)(progressMillisecond/100)/10 + "s",
                            centerWidth,
                            centerHeight + textOffset,
                            textPaint);

            // draw handle or the circle
            canvas.drawCircle((float)(centerWidth  + (Math.sin(progress * 2 * Math.PI) * radius)),
                              (float)(centerHeight - (Math.cos(progress * 2 * Math.PI) * radius)),
                              handleRadius,
                              progressPaint);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey! This looks really cool. Is it possible to only use a part of the activity? I want this at the bottom of my activity, and use some other elements at the top.

Comment: @adamNature Of course. Just take the inner static class CircularCountdown and use in as any other View. (You should probably also find some better way how to handle the size of the circle, because now it is fixed 200 units of something and you can expect it will break on different screen sizes.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Got it working just a couple hours after asking of course, stupid me. Its a great class, even with my plebish understandig of Android I'm being able to do fun things with it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing though. This class doesnt actually count DOWN, it counts up! Is there an easy fix to changing this? I tried messing inside the Runnable(), but couldnt get it working the way I wanted. Thanks again for a great class!

Comment: Try updating the code inside the Runnable:
    progressMillisecond = maxTime - (currentTime - startTime) % maxTime;

Comment: You are awesome! :D

Answer (score 1):

The solution of `Antimonit` has two significant problems:

1. Memory leak occure when you destroy activity/fragment with `circular clock view`, and show clock again.
2. All parameters are hardcoded in java class, and circular clock view class in not reusable.

Based on `Antimonit` code (thank You!), I create more reusable and memory safe solution. Now, almost all parameters can be set from `XML` file. At the end in the activity/fragment class we need invoke `startCount` method. I strongly recoment invoke `removeCallbacks` method when activity/fragment are going to be destroyed to avoid memory leaks.

**KakaCircularCounter.java class:**

```
public class KakaCircularCounter extends View {
public static final int DEF_VALUE_RADIUS = 250;
public static final int DEF_VALUE_EDGE_WIDTH = 15;
public static final int DEF_VALUE_TEXT_SIZE = 18;
private Paint backgroundPaint;
private Paint progressPaint;
private Paint textPaint;
private RectF circleBounds;
private long startTime;
private long currentTime;
private long maxTime;
private long progressMillisecond;
private double progress;
private float radius;
private float edgeHeadRadius;
private float textInsideOffset;
private KakaDirectionCount countDirection;
private Handler viewHandler;
private Runnable updateView;

public KakaCircularCounter(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

public KakaCircularCounter(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

public KakaCircularCounter(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
}

public KakaCircularCounter(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrSet) {
    if (attrSet == null) {
        return;
    }

    TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrSet, R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter);

    circleBounds = new RectF();
    backgroundPaint = setupBackground(typedArray);
    progressPaint = setupProgress(typedArray);
    textPaint = setupText(typedArray);

    textInsideOffset = (textPaint.descent() - textPaint.ascent() / 2) - textPaint.descent();

    radius = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_clockRadius, DEF_VALUE_RADIUS);
    edgeHeadRadius = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_edgeHeadRadius, DEF_VALUE_EDGE_WIDTH);

    countDirection = KakaDirectionCount.values()[typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_countFrom,
            KakaDirectionCount.MAXIMUM.ordinal())];

    typedArray.recycle();
}

private Paint setupText(TypedArray typedArray) {
    Paint t = new Paint();
    t.setTextSize(typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_textInsideSize, DEF_VALUE_TEXT_SIZE));
    t.setColor(typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_textInsideColor, Color.BLACK));
    t.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    return t;
}

private Paint setupProgress(TypedArray typedArray) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_clockWidth, DEF_VALUE_EDGE_WIDTH));
    p.setColor(typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_edgeBackground, Color.parseColor("#4D4D4D")));
    return p;
}

private Paint setupBackground(TypedArray ta) {
    Paint b = new Paint();
    b.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    b.setStrokeWidth(ta.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_clockWidth, DEF_VALUE_EDGE_WIDTH));
    b.setColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.KakaCircularCounter_clockBackground, Color.parseColor("#4D4D4D")));
    b.setAntiAlias(true);
    b.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
    return b;
}


public void startCount(long maxTimeInMs) {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.maxTime = maxTimeInMs;

    viewHandler = new Handler();
    updateView = () -> {
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        progressMillisecond = (currentTime - startTime) % maxTime;
        progress = (double) progressMillisecond / maxTime;
        KakaCircularCounter.this.invalidate();
        viewHandler.postDelayed(updateView, 1000 / 60);
    };
    viewHandler.post(updateView);
}

public void removeCallbacks() {
    viewHandler.removeCallbacks(updateView);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float centerWidth = getWidth() / 2f;
    float centerHeight = getHeight() / 2f;

    circleBounds.set(centerWidth - radius,
            centerHeight - radius,
            centerWidth + radius,
            centerHeight + radius);

    canvas.drawCircle(centerWidth, centerHeight, radius, backgroundPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(circleBounds, -90, (float) (progress * 360), false, progressPaint);

    canvas.drawText(getTextToDraw(),
            centerWidth,
            centerHeight + textInsideOffset,
            textPaint);

    canvas.drawCircle((float) (centerWidth + (Math.sin(progress * 2 * Math.PI) * radius)),
            (float) (centerHeight - (Math.cos(progress * 2 * Math.PI) * radius)),
            edgeHeadRadius,
            progressPaint);
}

@NonNull
private String getTextToDraw() {
    if (countDirection.equals(KakaDirectionCount.ZERO)) {
        return String.valueOf(progressMillisecond / 1000);
    } else {
        return String.valueOf((maxTime - progressMillisecond) / 1000);
    }
}
```

}

**KakaDirectionCount enum:**

```
public enum KakaDirectionCount {
    ZERO, MAXIMUM
}
```

**atributes file in values directory (kaka_circular_counter.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="KakaCircularCounter">
        <attr name="clockRadius" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="clockBackground" format="color"/>
        <attr name="clockWidth" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="edgeBackground" format="color"/>
        <attr name="edgeWidth" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="edgeHeadRadius" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="textInsideSize" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="textInsideColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="countFrom" format="enum">
            <enum name="ZERO" value="0"/>
            <enum name="MAXIMUM" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**example of using in xml file:**

```
    <pl.kaka.KakaCircularCounter
        android:id="@+id/circular_counter"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/backgroundTriangle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/backgroundTriangle"
        app:clockRadius="85dp"
        app:clockBackground="@color/colorTransparent"
        app:clockWidth="3dp"
        app:edgeBackground="@color/colorAccentSecondary"
        app:edgeWidth="5dp"
        app:edgeHeadRadius="1dp"
        app:textInsideSize="60sp"
        app:textInsideColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:countFrom="MAXIMUM"/>
```

**Example of using in activity or fragment:**

```
//the number in parameter is the value of the counted time
binding.circularCounter.startCount(12000);
```

**CAUTION: remember to remove callbacks when you destroy activity/fragment, because memory leak occure. For example:**

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding.circularCounter.removeCallbacks();
}
```