# CABasicAnimation not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to animate a circular stroke (from another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle)). I am trying to do it in a Cocoa based application.

However it's not working and `animationDidStop:finished:` is being immediately called with `finished` flag as `NO`. Why is this happening? Any pointers on how I can get some information why the `finished` flag is `NO`?

Here is the code I use:

Note: `quartzPath` and `NSColorToCGColor` are from categories on `NSColor` and `NSBezierPath`.

```
- (IBAction)animateCircle:(id)sender {

    int radius = 10;
    circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // Make a circular shape
    circle.path =  [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)] quartzPath] ;
    // Center the shape in self.view
    circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.vcForCellView.view.frame)-radius, 
                                  CGRectGetMidY(self.vcForCellView.view.frame)-radius);

    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    circle.fillColor =  [NSColor NSColorToCGColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    circle.strokeColor = [NSColor NSColorToCGColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    circle.lineWidth = 5;

    // Add to parent layer
    [self.vcForCellView.view.layer addSublayer:circle];

    // Configure animation
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 2.0; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;   // Remain stroked after the animation..

    // Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

    // Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    drawAnimation.delegate = self;

    // Add the animation to the circle
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

}
```

Also the following code:

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    CALayer *layer = [anim valueForKey:@"parentLayer"];
    NSLog(@"%@",layer);
    NSLog(@"%@",flag?@"YES":@"NO");
}
```

gives the following output:

**`2013-07-02 19:28:14.760 TicTacToe[16338:707] (null)`**
**`2013-07-02 19:28:14.761 TicTacToe[16338:707] NO`**

**UPDATE:**

The `animationDidStop:...` method gets called with `finished` as `YES` after I backed the view with a layer ( `[view setWantsLayer:YES]`). But still nothing is being shown on screen.

Here is the code for getting `CGPathRef` from `NSBezierPath`:

```
- (CGPathRef)quartzPath
{
    int i;
    NSInteger numElements;

    // Need to begin a path here.
    CGPathRef           immutablePath = NULL;

    // Then draw the path elements.
    numElements = [self elementCount];
    if (numElements > 0)
    {
        CGMutablePathRef    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        NSPoint             points[3];
        BOOL                didClosePath = YES;

        for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
        {
            switch ([self elementAtIndex:i associatedPoints:points])
            {
                case NSMoveToBezierPathElement:
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, points[0].x, points[0].y);
                    break;

                case NSLineToBezierPathElement:
                    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, points[0].x, points[0].y);
                    didClosePath = NO;
                    break;

                case NSCurveToBezierPathElement:
                    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, points[0].x, points[0].y,
                                          points[1].x, points[1].y,
                                          points[2].x, points[2].y);
                    didClosePath = NO;
                    break;

                case NSClosePathBezierPathElement:
                    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
                    didClosePath = YES;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Be sure the path is closed or Quartz may not do valid hit detection.
        if (!didClosePath)
            CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

        immutablePath = CGPathCreateCopy(path);
        CGPathRelease(path);
    }

    return immutablePath;
}
```

And I'm using 10.7 SDK and can't use the inbuilt `CGPath` method added with the new SDKs of `NSBezierPath`.

Comment: Is your view correctly configured to be layer backed / layer hosting? `[myView setWantsLayer:YES];` Otherwise I think the issue could be that the view has no layer so the shape layer is never added to the layer hierarchy.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist:  Aargh.. I shouldn't have missed that. Thanks a lot. :) If you post it as answer will you give you credit. Not the animationDidStop works as expected. Only thing is that i still can't see the drawing animation. :|

Comment: What is wrong with the drawing animation?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: Don't know. Its not the animation I think. I can't even seem to fill the shape layer with the color. The animation seems to be happening but nothing is being shown on screen. I don't know if anything is wrong with the  category method on NSBezierPath . I'll post them as well. and the log of `[anim valueForKey:@"parentLayer"]` stroll returns `null`

Comment: Does it work if you use `CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(rect, NULL);` instead of the NSBezierPath?

Comment: Well. It was working from the beginning. The co-ordinates I used was making it render outside bounds. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default views on OS X don't have layers attached to them so the likely problem is that `vcForCellView.view.layer` is `nil`. This means that the shape layer never gets added to the layer hierarchy so when the animation is added to the shape layer it is immediately cancelled  (as seen by `finished` being `NO`).

You can tell your view that it should be backed by a layer using: `[myView setWantsLayer:YES];`