# Setting the image of a UITableViewCell to a circle of a specific color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

On my table view, I want to display small circles of certain colors that will provide context for the information. The circles should be in the location that the image would usually be in (the left hand side). Is there an easy way to do this? I was thinking that I could create a new image view and simply draw on it using some drawing routines. The problem is I don't know any of these drawing routines, or at least I don't know how to use them outside of a `drawRect` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest way would be to include the different images in your bundle and conditionally set them to the cell's imageView's image property in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

However, if you're looking for alternative's you could subclass UITableViewCell, and use CAShapeLayers to draw them programmatically and add them to the cells layer in what ever position you want.

Here's an example of how to use CAShapeLayer to draw a circle:

[iPhone Core Animation - Drawing a Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle)

Comment: @Iowa15 Glad to hear it, need any more input while I'm here?