# Animating UIViews with bezierPathWithArcCenter

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I'm animating two UView on bezier path:

```
UIBezierPath *path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerPoint radius:160 startAngle:5.008935 endAngle:0.217025 clockwise:YES];
UIBezierPath *path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerPoint radius:160 startAngle:5.008935 endAngle:0.588981 clockwise:YES];

5.008935 rad = 286.990814 degrees
0.217025 rad = 12.434639 degrees
0.588981 rad = 33.746109 degrees

- (CAAnimationGroup *)animationForItem:(QuadCurveMenuItem *)item
{
CGFloat startAngle = DEGREES_2_RADIANS([Utilities pointPairToBearingDegrees:item.centerPoint secondPoint:item.startPoint]);
CGFloat endAngle = DEGREES_2_RADIANS([Utilities pointPairToBearingDegrees:item.centerPoint secondPoint:item.endPoint]);

UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:item.mainPoint radius:kQuadCurveMenuDefaultEndRadius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];

CAKeyframeAnimation *positionAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
positionAnimation.duration = self.duration;
positionAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[positionAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
positionAnimation.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
CGPathRelease(path);

CAAnimationGroup *animationgroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animationgroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:positionAnimation, nil];
animationgroup.duration = self.duration;
[animationgroup setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
animationgroup.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animationgroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;

return animationgroup;
}

- (void)performExpandMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated duration:(float)duration
{

    NSArray *itemToBeAnimated = [self allMenuItemsBeingDisplayed];

    id<QuadCurveAnimation> animation = self.noAnimation;
    if (animated) { animation = self.expandItemAnimation; }

    [animation setDuration:duration];

    for (int x = 0; x < [itemToBeAnimated count]; x++) {
        QuadCurveMenuItem *item = [itemToBeAnimated objectAtIndex:x];
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:item,@"menuItem",animation,@"animation", nil];

        [self performSelector:@selector(animateMenuItemToEndPoint:) withObject:dictionary afterDelay:0];
    }
}

- (void)animateMenuItemToEndPoint:(NSDictionary *)itemAndAnimation {
    id<QuadCurveAnimation> animation = [itemAndAnimation objectForKey:@"animation"];
    QuadCurveMenuItem *item = [itemAndAnimation objectForKey:@"menuItem"];

    CAAnimationGroup *expandAnimation = [animation animationForItem:item];

    [item.layer addAnimation:expandAnimation forKey:[animation animationName]];
    item.center = item.endPoint;
}
```

All views have same animation. Only difference is end point Angle (endAngle).

View on path2 is animating faster then view on path1. Why is this happening?

I noticed that it only happens when difference between endAngle and startAngle is greated then 90 degrees (case View 2 in this example).

Check video: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24732347/video.mov

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle/8021051#8021051

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Figure 1 in the [bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter%3aradius%3astartAngle%3aendAngle%3aclockwise%3a) documentation: For a "pie slice" in the upper right corner you have to use the parameters

startAngle:degreesToRadians(-90) endAngle:0 clockwise:YES
(The reason is that the default coordinate system on iOS has a x-axis pointing to the right, and a y-axis pointing down.)

Hope this info will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a more complete description of what you're doing. I'm guessing that you're creating a CAKeyframeAnimation using the 2 paths as the path property for the animation?

And are you saying that when you animate 2 different views using these paths, the view that is animated using path2 travels at more points/second than the view that is animated using path1?

Are both animations traveling the full length of their arc during the animation duration?

It stands to reason that an animation along a longer path will move faster in points/second than an animation over a shorter arc, because it has to travel a greater distance during the same time.

Comment: Check this video: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24732347/video.mov. You can see that last two dots do not have linear speed. Why? All animations have same duration and same timingFunction.

Comment: Except your code doesn't make sense. You show code that creates 2 paths, an then don't use either of them. Then you create a single keyframe animation and add it to a group. If you are asking about different timing between multiple animations, you need to post code that creates 2 or more animations that are exhibiting different behavior.

Comment: I cannot post whole code here. I'm using group because I also have rotation animation, but it is not important in my question, that's why I removed it. Those two paths are used as an example for two dots. Each dot has it's own path. Check my edited post, if you need more code, but I think it's not necessary for this issue.