# iOS: How to draw a circle step by step with NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, cgcontext

I'd like to draw a circle without filling (only border of the circle) step by step (like animated timer). 1 spin is equal 1 day (24 hours). I really don't know what to do.

### Steps I've made

1) I've tried https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress (it's too wide line of progress)

2) I've tried to draw a circle with many arcs.

Can you put me some code please. I really confused. Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

I'd like to use NSTimer because I have a button which allow user to stop drawning a circle. If user touch a button again - drawning will have to continue.

Comment: Is this the point where I'm supposed to say "GAH! Animating with timers?!" (I don't mean to be rude, it's just the wrong tool for the job and I see it being used incorrectly quite a lot)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I've just edited my question. I've added more details. I'd like you to help me out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would do is to create a path that is a circle and use that with a CAShapeLayer and animate the strokeEnd similar to what [I did in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021051/608157).

It would look something like this (but I didn't run this code so there may be typos and other mistakes):

```
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                      radius:radius
                                                  startAngle:0
                                                    endAngle:2.0*M_PI
                                                   clockwise:YES];

CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius);
circleLayer.path   = circle.CGPath;
circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.lineWidth   = 3.0; // your line width

CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.duration = 10.0; // your duration

// Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
drawAnimation.fromValue = @0;
drawAnimation.toValue   = @1;
```

Just note that both the path and the shape layer has a position so the circle path should be defined relative to the origin of the shape layers frame. It might be clearer to define the shape layer first and then create an oval inside of its bounds:

```
CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius);
circleLayer.position = center; // Set center of the circle

// Create a circle inside of the shape layers bounds
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleLayer.bounds];
circleLayer.path     = circle.CGPath;

// Same appearance configuration as before
circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.lineWidth   = 3.0; // your line width
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks. But `drawAnimation.duration = 10.0;` doesn't work for me, Everytime it's different. E.g. 10.0 is equal 11-12 seconds

Comment: The comment "your duration" was meant as: "put whatever value is suitable for you here".

Comment: No-no :) I said if I put 10.0 the animation will continue for 11-12 seconds, not 10. I'm so sorry for my bad english

Comment: Its because of Timer Coalescing http://www.timoliver.com.au/2014/01/25/disabling-timer-coalescing-in-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: Pause that animation when the user taps the button. Don't use a timer.

Answer (score 1):

If DACircleProgress[enter link description here](https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress) otherwise works for you, it looks like you can easily set the line thickness.

As opposed to have a simple `lineWidth` type property, it seems the author of that library sets the thickness based on a ratio to the radius of the circle. This exists as the `thicknessRatio` property of that class. For example, if your radius is 40, then setting `thicknessRatio` to 0.025 should yield a line width of 1. That library seems simple and well thought out - consider using it, or learning from it.

The default is set to 0.3, so a circle with a radius of 40 would have a progress line thickness of 12. That's probably what you were seeing.

Good luck!