# Animate fillColor property

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am trying to achieve the filling of a circle(something like a pie).
I want to fill it from 0 to 360
This is what i have done

```
CAShapeLayer *circleLayer=[CAShapeLayer layer];
    circleLayer.path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(150, 150) radius:100 startAngle:0 endAngle:360 clockwise:YES].CGPath;
    circleLayer.strokeColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    circleLayer.fillColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];




    //adding animation
    CABasicAnimation *basicAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"fillColor"];
    basicAnimation.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
    basicAnimation.fromValue=(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    basicAnimation.toValue=(id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    basicAnimation.duration=1.5f;
    basicAnimation.repeatCount=10;
    basicAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    [circleLayer addAnimation:basicAnimation forKey:@"fillColor"];
```

I am not able to figure out,how do i acheive the effect of color filling from start angle to end angle.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Core Animation - Drawing a Circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle)

Comment: i already tried the above example but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: at least 68 people seem to think it works

Comment: i am not sure but the fillColor property doesn't do anything in my code

Comment: If you are both filling and stroking the circle, change that to two shapes with the two colors that are only stroked. Then animate the strokeEnd of both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description of what you want to do is unclear. Are you trying to create a "clock wipe" effect, where the color change sweeps like the second hand of a clock?

If so, check out this demo app I created on github:

[**github animation demo project**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)

Look in particular at the description of the Clock Wipe animation in the read me file.

Here is what the clock wipe animation looks like:

[image]

This project animates the mask of an image view to do a clock wipe reveal animation, but it would be a simple matter to animate a shape layer as a content layer of a view instead of making it a mask.

Answer (score 0):

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
animation.duration = 0.7f;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[circleLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

Comment: this will only animate the boundary,i want the animation to be filled from the center radially

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a shape layer subclass for similar requirements. Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/adithyabhat/CircleFillAnimation/tree/master/CircleFilleAnimation/CircleFillAnimation). For your requirement the arc start radius is 0.0f and end radius is the circle radius. You can also refer the sample project in that link.