# Animate drawing of CALayer with spring animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, spring, animation, core-animation

I want to animate [drawing an arc onscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle) but I want it to have the spring effect found in iOS 7's `UIView animate... usingSpringDamping:` API. I know I can use Core Animation directly by creating a `CABasicAnimation` but then I lose out on the nice spring effect, and the built-in timing functions stop at `EaseOut`, which isn't really what I want. Ideally the arc would draw to a target angle, overshoot it, then bounce back and forth until it settled on the target.

Is there a way to do this without writing my own timing function / subclassing `CAAnimation`?

Comment: Use key frame animations.

Comment: I wrote a class that simulates spring animations using keyframe animations, which might be of use you. https://github.com/jwilling/JNWSpringAnimation It won't let you draw a path (like you seem to be wanting to do), but you can at least take inspiration from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `CASpringAnimation`, it has the same API as UIView Spring Animation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does spring animation on CALayer. If you don't mind using Swift.

```
SpringAnimation.animate(myCALayer,
                        keypath: "transform.rotation.x",
                        duration: 2.0,
                        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                        initialSpringVelocity: 1.8,
                        fromValue: 0,
                        toValue: Double(M_PI),
                        onFinished: nil)
```

Demo app: https://github.com/evgenyneu/SpringAnimationCALayer

Comment: And why didn't this guy just make a CAMediaTimingFunction for this?