# Save CoreAnimation sequence frame by frame

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

How can I save each frame of a CoreAnimation based animation (as image files)?

Here's my little playground scene. The animation lasts 2.4 seconds.

```
let stage = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 300, height: 300))
stage.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();

var dot = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
dot.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
dot.center = stage.center

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.4, animations: { () -> Void in
    dot.center.y = dot.center.y + 50
})
```

I know how to save a static UIView frame as PDF but I am not sure how to hook into the animation sequence while it happens and capture/save the view frame by frame.

## Option 1

As far as I see it I need to hook into the animation block and save the stage view for each frame (at a given frame rate?). How can I do this? Is there **some sort of callback** I can use?

## Option 2

While looking for a solution I came across another option that looks even more promising (based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle/8021051#8021051) and this awesome [blog post](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/)). Using a `CBAnimation`, setting a `timingFunction` and then  setting the `timeOffset` to the progress states I want to render.

Here's an example for the frame at 50% progress (using a different example here).

```
var drawAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
…
drawAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
drawAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
drawAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)

circle.addAnimation(drawAnimation, forKey: "drawCircleAnimation")

circle.speed = 0.0;
circle.timeOffset = 0.5
```

The problem is that I cannot **capture** this `timeOffset` based animation state. When I render the view I only get the final state instead of the frozen animation frame at 0.5.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.