# CAShapeLayer Multiple Drawing At Once Swift 2.0

Tags: swift2, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I want to create a visual representation of 3 different numbers that relate to how much of something a user has. I know it's probably best to use CAShapeLayer.

So I need to draw one circle radius at 40%, another(different color) at 65%, and another(diff color) at say 90%. They all need to be on top of each either. Similar to the image below.
[image]

Are there any Github classes to help with this? Also, can I animate the radiuss being filled concurrently?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had any progress with this? I'm also looking into animating a clock counting down and what I've found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991086/iphone-core-animation-drawing-a-circle/8021051) to be a bit helpful.

Comment: @SylvanDAsh Yes I have, solved my problem. How can I help you with it?

Comment: drawing the background circle was a bit problematic initially, but after reading up some more on `CAShapeLayer`, I was able to resolve it. Now I just need to know how to make the borders look embossed and I'll be good to go ^^

Comment: @SylvanDAsh ah I see, interesting. Maybe a shadow on the inner or outer to do an embossed look. Not sure how to add a shadow though in that case.